# Window Controls moved to right hand side

Tags: window-buttons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I move all the window controls to the right?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right)

without realising, the Windows Controls (max, min, close) have been moved to the right hand side without me realising. I was just wondering, how would I go about changing it back to the left and does anyone know why this might have happened?

This is in 12.04 precise.

Thanks