# Window buttons stuck on right side

Tags: window-buttons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Window Controls moved to right hand side](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124015/window-controls-moved-to-right-hand-side)

After I upgraded to Quantal the window buttons of not maximized windows mysteriously moved to the right having the order they have in the panel when maximized. And I can't put them back to the left which is really annoying. I guess something was messed up during the upgrade.

I tried **Ubuntu Tweak** and **gconf-editor** so far but changing the button layout there doesn't do anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you closing this as duplicate? Solution from 12.04 doesn't work.

Comment: I was also wondering why they chose the link above as a duplicate, because the solution that worked for me isn't in there.