# Window controls not moving to right side in 12.10

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Window Controls moved to right hand side](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124015/window-controls-moved-to-right-hand-side)

I'm using **Gnome Classic**, and I prefer my window controls to be on the right side.

I've followed the [instructions in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/125983/17041), and in `gconf-editor`, I edited the value for `apps/metacity/general/button_layout` to be `:minimize,maximize,close`. This worked before in 12.04.

However, in a fresh install of 12.10, it is no longer taking effect. The window controls are staying on the left side.

How do I get the window controls to be on the right side?

Comment: read further down - two 12.10 answers given.  Strictly speaking this is a duplicate and I've closed this.

Comment: @fossfreedom: Fair enough to close this question, but I believe that answer came in *after* I posted my question. Just saying.