# Positon of exit button

Tags: 12.04, application-development, settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Window Controls moved to right hand side](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124015/window-controls-moved-to-right-hand-side)
>   [How can I move all the window controls to the right?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right)

How can I set up the exit button on aplications to be on the right side of the window?
 I use ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: This might help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124015/window-controls-moved-to-right-hand-side http://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right