# Move Window Controls of Maximised Window to Right

Tags: unity, 13.04, window-buttons

I can move my window controls from following
[this](https://askubuntu.com/q/124015/) and 
[this](https://askubuntu.com/q/174292/) discussion from askubuntu.com.

Normal Window Controls do work fine. However maximized windows don't seem to follow this rule. When window is maximized from Normal State to Maximized state, window controls is shown at the default top-left position.

Switching between different behavior for Maximized window and Normal window is often confusing and is a real pain.

[image]

---

**So My Question is**
**Is this a behavior by design?**
**Is there a workaround to move window controls of maximized window to right?**

---

I'm using 13.04 version of Ubuntu

Comment: Yes. This behaviour is by design. There isn't room on the right of the panel for them.

Comment: @Seth- Is there a workaround? Say by moving window controls to it's own title bar. Either by removing or retaining global menu.

Comment: I think that is possible. I don't have time to write an answer right now, but I'll try to later.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't find the option again. It might have been removed...

Comment: @Seth -After Googling for very long time, currently it seems there's no way to do this. I'm not sure weather it's a bug. But adding a feature in unity to move window controls to right would be nice feature.

Comment: Reporting a bug is also the way you create feature requests iirc.